# Block multiple directories and file types

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want block some paths and file types in htaccess.

I have regex like this: `\/(libs|public)\/(.*).*\.(css|js|jpe?g|png|bmp|ttf)` which works well at test server https://regex101.com/

for my example string: `/libs/test/any.css?number=123`.

When I move my condition into htaccess my example string is allowed. But it must be blocked with 403 because is started with `libs` string.

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/(libs|public)/(.*).*\.(css|js|jpe?g|png|bmp|ttf)#">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    satisfy all
</If>
```

because I want to block paths started in my condition (libs|public).

This request `/allowedfiles/libs/test/any.css?number=123` must not be blocked.

Please help what am I dooing wrong?

Comment: _“Please help what am I dooing wrong?”_ - well for starters, you apparently still think _“doesn’t work”_ was an appropriate problem description. What happens? Do you get access to more than intended? Does stuff you didn’t want to be blocked, get blocked? Errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below, it requires mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(libs|public)\/(.*).*\.(css|js|jpe?g|png|bmp|ttf)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```